# Setting Panel.Background on a Border object?

Tags: wpf

I am not understanding how this [Button Template Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) from Microsoft is working... In its storyboards for its various states, it is setting Panel.Background for a target type of Border (example below). I don't see that Border inherits from Panel in any way.

Setting the TargetProperty to Border.Background... seems to work the same way. I would just like to understand the nuances of what is going on... Every time I think I have a handle on 
WPF, I run into something I can't explain :(

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame
        KeyTime="0"
        Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because dependency properties can be reused, the `Border` just adds the property of the `Panel` via [`AddOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DependencyProperty.AddOwner.aspx). The property field is initialized like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
         Panel.BackgroundProperty.AddOwner(typeof(Border), ...
```

So the `Panel.Background` property is the same as the `Border.Background` property.

Comment: Ahh, just when I thought I knew everything about WPF... I guess you learn something new every day :) Nice one!

Comment: @alfonso: WPF is a bottomless well :D