# Help converting NotifyOnChange Properties to Dependency Properties

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

What is the best way of converting the fictional code below to dependency properties?
Where the Date Property will be in another control?

```
    [DependsOn("Date")]
    public int Year
    {
        get { return Date.Year; }
        set { Date.Year = value; }
    }

    [NotifyOnChange]
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get; set; 
    }
```

Comment: Some Clarification: Setting the Year will notify Date has changed, setting Date will notify Year has changed.

Comment: Your fictional code shows both properties on the same class, but in your intro paragraph you say the Date property will be in "another control". So does that mean these two properties will be on two different classes, and the object with Year will have some kind of reference to the object with Date?

Comment: It was just an extra question in case it made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency properties can be **dependent** on one another via `Binding`, `Style`, `Trigger`, `Template` etc. In certain cases they inherit values like [DataContext](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/07/14/who-set-the-datacontext/). In other cases they copy the values of the owner like Border's [background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141831/setting-panel-background-on-a-border-object).

In your case do you want to create two dependency properties which by default **depend** on each other at declaration level itself i.e. in code behind?

If so, your `Date` can be one Dep.Prop say `DateProperty`. and `Year` can be other say `YearProperty`. In `DateProperty` and `YearProperty`'s `PropertyChangedCallBack` metadata, change each other taking care that they do not fall in **deadlock**.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, it is just really verbose, so I was hoping there was an aspect I was missing.